# Resume - Anchor node to top left and other node below it

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, resume

I am trying to build a resume using latex. I am trying to replicate some stuff done in MS word to latex.

Below is the image of what I am trying to replicate

[image]

So far I've used the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
%\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pagenumbering{gobble} 

\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{394456}
\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [rectangle, fill=darkgray, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=3cm] (box) at (current page.north){};


\node [anchor=east] (name) at (box) {%
    \fontsize{45pt}{65pt}\color{white}%
    {\textbf{John Doe}}
};


%\node [anchor=east] (name) at (box) {%
%   \fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\color{white}%
%   {\textbf{Job Title}}
%};

\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{1cm}
\vspace{-2\parskip}


\end{document}
```

The output from above code is [image]

I am new to latex and I would like to know how can I move name to top left just like shown in image I am trying to replicate and how to change the font type?

I've commented a piece of code in my code that causes an overlap of `Name` and `Job title`. How can I move it below the name?

Third and the last thing how can I add a node to add picture to extreme mid-right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome! Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
%\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagenumbering{gobble} 

\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{394456}
\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [rectangle, fill=darkgray, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=3cm] (box) at (current page.north){};


\node [text=white,font=\fontsize{45pt}{65pt}\bfseries\sffamily,anchor=north
west] (name) at ([xshift=2em,yshift=-2em]box.north west) {%
John Doe
};
\node [text=blue!20,font=\fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\bfseries\sffamily,anchor=north
west] (name) at ([xshift=0.5ex]name.south west) {%
Job title
};

\node[anchor=east] at ([xshift=-2em]box.east)
{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems good will accept your answer if you could answer last part of question. How can I add a node to add image?

Comment: @FurqanHashim Sorry, I missed that part, and added it now.

Answer (score 2):

Is this okay?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,remember picture,overlay]
\path (current page.north west) node[below right,fill=darkgray,minimum width=\paperwidth,minimum height=3cm] (box){};

\path (box.west) node[right=5mm,align=left] 
{{\fontsize{45pt}{65pt}\color{white}\textbf{Ivanka Trump}}\\[2mm]
{\fontsize{30pt}{20pt}\color{cyan}Advisor to POTUS}\\[2mm]
{\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\color{white}workforce development \& entrepreneurship}};

% image and info from https://twitter.com/IvankaTrump/photo
\path (box.east)--++(180:2.5) coordinate (img);
\begin{scope}
\clip (img) circle(1);
\path (img) node[circle,scale=.15]{\includegraphics{ivanka.jpg}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer to your direct question has to be no.

Comment: @Anush:  I change that Ivanka picture? She is beautiful! Do you hate her or something?